# SonarQube doesn't store all results in the database?

Tags: sonarqube

I am aware I should not use the database directly from SonarQube, but this is a one-shot complex thing, and saves me days if I can do it directly from the database.

I need to know the amount of classes per project, where the amount of lines is less than 200. So far no problem creating this in SQL.

Only problem I have: for 2 projects, this information isn't stored at all in the database! In the GUI from SonarQube I can see this measure for each file, but than in the database these files have only 1 measures stored (technical debt).

My guess is that for some strange reasons these measures are calculated on the fly for this project? Could that be? And is there a way to force SonarQube to store proejct measures for each file in the database? I tried with the sonar.analysis.mode=analysis parameter but that didn't work?

Thanks a lot and regards,

Pieter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was due to the query. this is the right query

```
SELECT metrics.description, root.name, COUNT(project_measures.metric_id) AS AmountOfFiles,
    SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value < 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Less200,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ((project_measures.value >= 200) AND (project_measures.value <= 1000)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Between200And1000,
    SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) More1000
FROM project_measures
    INNER JOIN metrics on project_measures.metric_id = metrics.id
    INNER JOIN snapshots on project_measures.snapshot_id = snapshots.id
    INNER JOIN projects root on snapshots.root_project_id = root.id
WHERE metrics.id = '1' /*Line: code lines + comments + blanc lines*/
        and root.scope = 'PRJ' /*projects*/
        and snapshots.scope = 'FIL'
        and root.name like '%'      /* '%' to show all projects*/
        GROUP BY root.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by your question. Are you saying that, when using your SQL queries, you have the results correct for all but 2 projects, whose metrics appear in the SonarQube dashboard?

I suppose the problem cannot come from your SQL queries?
Have you been running these 2 projects recently?
Try clearing your browser cache?

Regards.

Comment: I'm very sure about it. This is for isntacne the query I use (see underneath).

In a series of projects I did, these were somewhere in the middle. I removed them, tried it again, but still the same behaviour... I rebooted my laptop (everything runs lcoally), still the same days afterwards

Comment: SELECT metrics.description, root.name, COUNT(project_measures.metric_id) AS AmountOfFiles,
SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value < 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Less200,
SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) More1000
FROM project_measures
INNER JOIN metrics on project_measures.metric_id = metrics.id
INNER JOIN projects on projects.id = project_measures.snapshot_id
LEFT JOIN projects root on projects.root_id = root.id
 WHERE projects.scope = 'FIL'
and metrics.id = '1' /*Line: code lines*/
and root.scope = 'PRJ'GROUP BY root.name

Comment: the problem DID come from the SQL query :-/ see underneath to get the right query:

Comment: SELECT metrics.description, root.name, COUNT(project_measures.metric_id) AS AmountOfFiles,
 SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value < 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Less200,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ((project_measures.value >= 200) AND (project_measures.value <= 1000)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Between200And1000,
    SUM(CASE WHEN project_measures.value > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) More1000
FROM project_measures
    INNER JOIN metrics on project_measures.metric_id = metrics.id
    INNER JOIN snapshots on project_measures.snapshot_id = snapshots.id
    INNER JOIN projects root on snapshots.root_project_id = root.id

Comment: WHERE metrics.id = '1' /*Line: code lines + comments + blanc lines*/
        and root.scope = 'PRJ' /*projects*/
        and snapshots.scope = 'FIL'
        and root.name like '%'  /* '%' to show all projects*/
     GROUP BY root.name